# pythonを使った重み付きの多重指向グラフの描画について

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

pythonを使用してノードの座標を指定した状態でエッジの重み付き多重指向グラフを描画したいのですが，
何か良い方法はないでしょうか．

networkxとpyplotを使用して描画してみたのですが矢印同士が重なって表示されてしまうためうまくいきませんでした．

```
nodes = pd.DataFrame([[[1, 3]], [[0, 2]], [[3, 3]], [[5, 2]], [[2, 4]]], columns=['coords'])
nodes.index = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
edges = pd.DataFrame([['A','B', 4], ['B','A', 20], ['C','B', 3], ['D','D' ,10], ['C','A', 7], ['E','A' ,2], ['D','C' ,15], ['C','E', 8], ['D','A', 2]], columns=['start', 'end', 'weight'])

G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(nodes.index)
for index, row in edges.iterrows():
    G.add_edge(row.start, row.end, weight=row.weight)

nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, nodes.coords, font_size=16)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, nodes.coords, weight=edges.weight)
nx.draw(G, nodes.coords)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

エッジ(矢印)を重ねたくないなら、graphvizを使うのがよいと思います。
重みでエッジの位置を短くすることもできますが(※)、重みはエッジのラベルで表現することもできます。
jupyter-notebookで確かめたことはありませんが、AnacondaのSpyderで書いたことがあります。
※graphvizでは思うような位置にノードやエッジを配置するのは難しいですし、graphvizの良さが活かせません。

---

以下コードサンプルです。

```
import graphviz
g = graphviz.Digraph(format='svg')
g.attr('node', shape='circle')
g.attr('node', style ='filled')
g.attr('node', fillcolor='orange')
g.attr('node', color='orange')

for node in nodes.index:
    g.node(node, node)

for index, row in edges.iterrows():
    g.attr('edge', weight=str(row.weight))
    g.edge(row.start, row.end, label='{weight:'+str(row.weight)+'}')

print(g)
g.view()
```

実行するときは、質問された方のコードに追記してください。
※実行には質問された方のコードの先頭に以下も追加してください。

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
```

元の画像
[image: 質問者のコード実行結果]
graphvizによる描画
[image: graphvizによる描画]

Comment: 最近plantumlでもgraphvizが書けることに気づきました。